# rustle sound in all of my audio devices

Tags: audio

I've always had the problem that I can hear a rustle sound when i play a sound on my computer. If there is no sound played, the rustle sound is gone. But as soon as I play a song, or even simple windows sounds it appears again as long as the sound is played. The sound was there on my old pc and on my new one too. I also bought a new headset, which has usb (the headset i had before had aux) but the sound is still there, as on my old headset too. I can't turn the volume down on the headset, so the rustle sound would disappear, which worked on my old headset, but not on this one since this just turns down the volume on my pc itself (i guess that's because my new headset has a usb port and not aux). I don't know why the sound is there nor what is causing the sound?

(excuse my bad english, i'm also not good at explaining things but i still hope someone could help me.)

Comment: I suspect you have some sort of electromagnetic interference (EMI) that's getting inducted into the analog audio lines leading to your headphones' speakers. Can you put a mic up to your headphones and record the sound? Hearing what it sounds like can give additional clues as to what it could be.

Comment: Let's just hope your situation is not as crazy as this guy's: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6E0O8UtObU

Comment: it's more like a hissing noise. i can't record it, because my mic can't pick it up, but it's still as loud that i can hear it clearly. the sound in this video is very similar to the noise that i can hear. it's not as loud as in the video but if you turn down the volume of the video it's approximately the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyEvkhgJcDk